# How to set the download folder for Edge in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am writing automated tests using Selenium. I want to set the download directory in Edge so that I can download files as part of my test. There is an EdgeOptions object that I can provide when creating the EdgeDriver, but I don't know what to set on the EdgeOptions.

I know the equivalent of how to do this in Chrome

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\temp")
```

and Firefox

```
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", @"C:\temp")
```

But, how do I do the same thing in Edge? And get it to download automatically without a save prompt?

Comment: I think from webdriver it is not possible. see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007004/how-to-spcify-the-download-location-for-ie11-and-edge-browsers-using-selenium-bi

Comment: You can do it via regkey: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/change-default-download-location-in-edge/74677e11-1f32-41ec-b825-da0ac0a52215

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for Edge like this:

```html
// hide driver Console? true/false 
EdgeDriverService service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; // hide Console

// change Standard-Download-Path
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
var downloadDirectory = "C:\temp";

// Setting custom download directory
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);

// start Selenium Driver:
webdriver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);

// max. Window
webdriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Prany already mentioned, probably there is no way to set download automatically. And if I right understood, you want to handle with native window dialogue, when you are clicking on download button. Selenium cannot interact with native windows, but you can use this [framework](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library). The sample code would be like this:

```
// Press the A Key Down
KeyboardSimulator.KeyDown(Keys.A);

// Let the A Key back up
KeyboardSimulator.KeyUp(Keys.A);

// Press A down, and let up (same as two above)
KeyboardSimulator.KeyPress(Keys.A);

// Simulate (Ctrl + C) shortcut, which is copy for most applications
KeyboardSimulator.SimulateStandardShortcut(StandardShortcut.Copy);

// This does the same as above
KeyboardSimulator.KeyDown(Keys.Control);
KeyboardSimulator.KeyPress(Keys.C);
KeyboardSimulator.KeyUp(Keys.Control);
```

So you can simulate `Ctrl + V` keyboard action and `Enter` action. Hope it helps.